# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser - Multipile Panels

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to programmatically add a ChromiumWebBrowser control to an application I'm developing. These are the steps I'm following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        //Initializa
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        textBox1.Text = "https://www.Google.com";
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(textBox1.Text);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
       
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
    }

    private void Chrome_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.Address;
        }));

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chrome.Load(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

i try display in one form, few panels, is possible?

image: https://prnt.sc/ublzvc

Comment: What do you mean by i try display in one form, few panels, is possible?  You can load multiple browsers on the same form.

Comment: i cant, its showed me only 1

Comment: You've only created one in your code.

Comment: so what to do to created more?

Comment: Add more panels,  add more ChromiumWebBrowser instances.

Comment: tnx i only add Chorme2 to all chorme variables